# How to permanently set kernel parameters in UEFI boot?

Tags: boot, kernel, uefi

I know how to do it in GRUB2, but I'm planning on converting my current install to UEFI.

Right now I have the following parameters:

```
quiet splash vt.global_cursor_default=0 
vt.default_red=0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 
vt.default_grn=0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 
vt.default_blu=0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
```

How do I make sure these get transferred to the EFI boot loader when converting, or how do I make sure I put them there myself? I mean, even if you assure me this would get transferred by boot-repair or something, to what file does it go?

Comment: the setting are in the config file not the boot loader.

Comment: What is that file, might I ask?

Comment: I could simply edit it with these parameters or is it a process, like with update-grub etc?

Comment: The file is `/etc/default/grub`. `grub` is used anyway.

Comment: You should have this in your /etc/default/grub already or how are you now doing it? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Configuring_GRUB_2 See #9 and add there: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" `  Never seen this before, but some info: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=167717

Comment: So... If I use UEFI grub is used anyway? Huh. I thought UEFI-installing Ubuntu would avoid the need for grub entirely. Thanks!

Comment: UEFI is a boot mode.  grub is a boot loader. one does not eliminate the other

Comment: There are multiple boot loaders for both BIOS and EFI. GRUB 2 is available for both, and is Ubuntu's default boot loader for both. You can use something else if you prefer, and there are cases when doing so may be desirable; but if GRUB is working for you, sticking with it probably makes sense. See [my page on the subject](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) for a rundown of what EFI boot loaders exist for Linux.